# Error propagation dataframe using Montecarlo simulation

Tags: r, function, dataframe, montecarlo, propagation

I am doing error analysis of predictive models and I need to calculate global error, this is, I need to calculate the resultant error from propagation of
indirect measurements errors. My data "df" looks like something similar to this

[image: x y x_se y_se 1.43 0.64 2.00 0.09 2.25 0.47 2.00 0.07 2.36 0.72 2.00 0.07 2.05 0.63 2.00 0.07 1.54 0.90 2.00 0.09 1.31 0.94 2.00 0.10 1.48 0.68 2.00 0.09]

Where 'x' and 'y' are the measured variables, and 'x_se' and 'y_se' the standard errors of these measurements

I have used function 'propagate' from package 'qpcR' for the first row

```
EXPR <-  expression((0.1*x)*(y/(y+0.1)))
x <- c(1.43, 2)
y <- c(0.64, 0.09)
DF <- cbind(x, y)
res <- propagate(expr = EXPR, data = DF, type = "stat",do.sim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
res$summary
```

or this one from the package 'metRology'

```
expr <- expression((0.1*a)*(b/(b+0.1)))
x <- list(a=1.43, b=0.64)
u <- list(2,0.1)
u.expr<-uncert(expr, x, u, method="MC",B=200)
u.expr
```

both of them work, but I do not know how to apply any of these functions to the entire df.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution to obtain the `res$summary` for each row of your dataframe.

You first create a custom function `my_fun` that does what you were trying to do for a single row of the dataframe. Then, you `apply` this function to each row of your dataframe. The end result would be a `list` with as many elements as your dataframe rows.

```
my_fun <- function(r){
  EXPR <- expression((0.1 * x) * (y / (y + 0.1)))
  x <- c(r[["x"]], r[["x_se"]])
  y <- c(r[["y"]], r[["y_se"]])
  DF <- cbind(x, y)
  res <- propagate(expr = EXPR, data = DF, type = "stat", do.sim = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
  return(res$summary)
}

set.seed(1)
apply(df, 1, my_fun)
```

Output

```
[[1]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1233798  NaN  0.1233898
Std.dev.    0.1726114   NA  0.1730206
Median      0.1234929   NA         NA
MAD         0.1708902   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.2153721   NA -0.2157244
Conf.upper  0.4686238   NA  0.4625041

[[2]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1849104  NaN  0.1849310
Std.dev.    0.1645677   NA  0.1650419
Median      0.1851380   NA         NA
MAD         0.1652076   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.1401244   NA -0.1385452
Conf.upper  0.5155102   NA  0.5084072

[[3]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.2070037  NaN  0.2070098
Std.dev.    0.1754712   NA  0.1756395
Median      0.2057387   NA         NA
MAD         0.1768489   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.1308923   NA -0.1372374
Conf.upper  0.5528197   NA  0.5512569

[[4]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1766511  NaN  0.1766596
Std.dev.    0.1723788   NA  0.1726441
Median      0.1744966   NA         NA
MAD         0.1736575   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.1552201   NA -0.1617167
Conf.upper  0.5203006   NA  0.5150359

[[5]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1384704  NaN  0.1384753
Std.dev.    0.1798246   NA  0.1800144
Median      0.1376255   NA         NA
MAD         0.1782177   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.2151249   NA -0.2143465
Conf.upper  0.4946514   NA  0.4912970

[[6]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1182867  NaN  0.1182874
Std.dev.    0.1805740   NA  0.1807828
Median      0.1184392   NA         NA
MAD         0.1805303   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.2378475   NA -0.2360404
Conf.upper  0.4731363   NA  0.4726152

[[7]]
                  Sim Perm       Prop
Mean        0.1287621  NaN  0.1287730
Std.dev.    0.1740355   NA  0.1743982
Median      0.1256472   NA         NA
MAD         0.1740543   NA         NA
Conf.lower -0.2106699   NA -0.2130411
Conf.upper  0.4720430   NA  0.4705872
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it seems a bit odd, the values of mean and std. dev on the column Prop seem all the same after between output 2-7.

Comment: @marlaska You're right, I wrote something wrong in the custom function. I did not have to refer to the dataframe `df` but only to the row `r`. I slightly adjusted the solution, and indeed now I obtain different results for each row